# how to access value of array in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

I am building an Android app in Titanium Studio with a Rest api (Apigee Baas) 
    as the backend component.
    I have some data in the Apigee Baas for example: name, address, attendance etc.

First in my code, I get the response from Rest API in the following manner..

```
         "entities" : [ {
              "uuid" : "8780273a-d210-11e4-81a4-cba5dc698934",
              "type" : "attendance",
              "created" : 1427192916259,
              "modified" : 1427192916259,
              "attendance" : [ {
              "date" : "10-09-1991",
              "atn" : "0"
     } ],
 "disputes" : "None",
"metadata" : {
"path" : "/attendances/8780273a-d210-11e4-81a4-cba5dc698934"
},
"password" : "1122",
"servicepro" : "pqrst",
"username" : "priyankaa"
} ],//json object response
```

I have tried the following code in Titanium Studio.

```
index.js file


function doClick(e){
        var url = "api.usergrid.com/PRI_95616/LOGIN/attendances?ql=select * where
        username= '"+$.usertf.value.toString()+"'
        and password='"+$.passtf.value.toString()+"'";

        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        // function called when the response data is available
        onload : function(e) {
        var params={};
        var json=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info('resp is'+this.responseText);
        var  user=json.entities[0].username;
        params["username"]=user;
        var pass=json.entities[0].password;         
        params["password"]=pass;
        var servp=json.entities[0].servicepro;         
        params["servicepro"]=servp;
        var atnd=json.entities[0].attendance[0].atn;         
        params["attendance"]=atnd;
        Ti.API.info('atn'+atnd);
        var atndate=json.entities[0].attendance[0].date;         
        params["attendance"]=atndate;
        Ti.API.info('atn'+atndate);

     if((user==$.usertf.value.toString() && pass==$.passtf.value.toString())
     {
        var window = Alloy.createController('profile', params).getView();
        window.open();

     }
     else{
        alert('error');
     };

 },

 onerror : function(e) {
    Ti.API.debug(e.error);
    alert('error');
 },
 timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("GET", url);
 // Send the request.
 client.send();//http request
 }

 $.index.open();
```

here attendance is an array of two objects atn and date which is stored in apigee bass.
Now I am getting the attendance value but when i am passing this attendance value i.e
array to another controller using params it is not accessed there. 
other values example username address is properly accessed. only the attendance value is not accessed..
Below is my profile.js file. this is my another controller where i am accessing these values.

```
profile.js 


var args = arguments[0] || {};
$.tff.text=args.username;
$.sertf.text=args.servicepro;
$.prevtf.text=args.attendance[0];
Ti.API.info('ath prof: '+args.attendance.atn);
Ti.API.info('ath date prof: '+args.date);
Ti.API.info('atnd:'+args.attendance[0].atn);
```

here in profile.js the array attendance is not getting accessed.
 How to access these array elemnents 
 Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not sending `attendance` as array from `index.js` and trying to access it in `profile.js`
if you will change

```
var atndate=json.entities[0].attendance[0].date;         
params["attendance"]=atndate;
```

to

```
var atndate=json.entities[0].attendance[0];         
params["attendance"]=atndate;
```

I think it will work.

Also you are overwriting `params["attendance"]` in your code.

Hope it helps.